# In Laravel: How to apply many filters to an entire set of routes based on their URI?

Tags: php, laravel-4, routes

In Laravel framework: Documentations ([route filter section](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters)) says:

> You may also specify that a filter applies to an entire set of routes based on their URI.
>
> ```
> Route::filter('admin', function()
> {
>     //
> });
>
> Route::when('admin/*', 'admin');
> ```

What if I have more than one filter and wanted to apply them all on an entire set of routes based on their URI? Should I apply them like this:

```
Route::when('admin/*', 'filter_1');
Route::when('admin/*', 'filter_2');
Route::when('admin/*', 'filter_3');
```

Or I can put them all in an array and apply them like this:

```
Route::when('admin/*', array('filter_1', 'filter_2', 'filter_3'));
```

Comment: Your question could use some question marks.

Comment: Can you not use `Route::group` in your situation?  Then apply the filters using a pope to that collection?

Comment: Try both solutions, you can answer it yourself. I'm pretty sure the first will work.

Comment: @Mr.Blackus The first solution works pretty well (it is from the documentation), my question was: Is the second solutions works exactly as the first solution or not?

Comment: Take a look to https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Answer (score 0):

After trying I have found that using

```
Route::when('admin/*', array('filter_1', 'filter_2', 'filter_3'));
```

will perform the same result, so YES, I can use the above line instead of the next 3 lines

```
Route::when('admin/*', 'filter_1');
Route::when('admin/*', 'filter_2');
Route::when('admin/*', 'filter_3');
```

And note that filters will be applied respectively, which means `filter_1` will be applied first, and if everything is ok `filter_2` will apply and so on.